# Microsoft Access - Link pictures to database automatically based on folder directory + firstname lastname

Tags: vba, image, ms-access

Hi I cant find anything regarding this, would be great if someone could point me in the right direction.

I have an access database with 4000 gym members.
I want to add profile pictures by linking from a given directory.
I dont want to manually link 4000 pictures

I want it to automatically search in the directory and match the firstname + last name + DOB of the member with the picture which will have the identical 
eg: bobjones05121989

Thanks ahead for your help.

Comment: Too broad question, need additional info. Where do you get the firstname + last name + DOB from? A form I presume? Are you looking to store the picture path to the database or simply display it as soon as the form loads? (if that's the case). Please clarify.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes the data will be from a form. I'm only looking to display, eg link. not store within database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Access 2007 or later? Use the ControlSource property of Image control. An expression can construct the file path, like:

`="C:\somepath\" & [FirstName] & [LastName] & Format([DOB], "ddmmyyyy") & ".jpg"`

If image doesn't exist the Image control will be blank.

Answer (score 0):

Try this when the form loads.

You need to change the field names to the actual names of your database.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim imagepath As String
    With Me
        imagepath = "Drive:\" & LCase(![FirstName]) & LCase(![LastName]) & Format(![DOB], "ddmmyyyy") & ".jpg"
    End With

    If Len(Dir(imagepath)) > 0 Then
        Me.ImageControl.Picture = imagepath
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If using Access 2007 or later, can just set the ControlSource property of an Image control with an expression that builds the file path. No VBA needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the function *UrlContent* to link from some other field(s) than ID, and not (as here) download anything (you have the files already) but just return the path of the picture:

```
' Download (picture) file from a URL of a hyperlink field to a
' (temporary) folder, and return the full path to the downloaded file.
'
' This can be used as the control source for a bound picture control.
' If no Folder is specified, the user's IE cache folder is used.
'
' Typical usage in the RecordSource for a form or report where Id is
' the unique ID and Url is the hyperlink field holding the URL to
' the picture file to be displayed:
'
'   - to a cached file where parameter Id is not used:
'
'   Select *, UrlContent(0, [Url]) As Path From SomeTable;
'
'   - or, where Id is used to create the local file name:
'
'   Select *, UrlContent([Id], [Url], "d:\somefolder") As Path From SomeTable;
'
' Then, set ControlSource of the bound picture control to: Path
'
' 2017-05-28. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function UrlContent( _
    ByVal Id As Long, _
    ByVal Url As String, _
    Optional ByVal Folder As String) _
    As Variant

    Const NoError   As Long = 0
    Const Dot       As String = "."
    Const BackSlash As String = "\"
   
    Dim Address     As String
    Dim Ext         As String
    Dim Path        As String
    Dim Result      As String
   
    ' Strip leading and trailing octothorpes from URL string.
    Address = HyperlinkPart(Url, acAddress)
    ' If Address is a zero-length string, Url was not wrapped in octothorpes.
    If Address = "" Then
        ' Use Url as is.
        Address = Url
    End If
   
    If Folder = "" Then
        ' Import to IE cache.
        Result = DownloadCacheFile(Address)
    Else
        If Right(Folder, 1) <> BackSlash Then
            ' Append a backslash.
            Folder = Folder & BackSlash
        End If
   
        ' Retrieve extension of file name.
        Ext = StrReverse(Split(StrReverse(Address), Dot)(0))
        ' Build full path for downloaded file.
        Path = Folder & CStr(Id) & Dot & Ext
       
        If DownloadFile(Address, Path) = NoError Then
            Result = Path
        End If
    End If
   
    UrlContent = Result
   
End Function
```

An article and a full demo can be found here:

[Show pictures directly from URLs in Access forms and reports](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/29679/Show-pictures-directly-from-URLs-in-Access-forms-and-reports.html)

Comment: This is not applicable as I understand it, since the pictures are already in a directory, and not on the internet. So getting them using an HTTP download is not needed.

Comment: The answer says to modify code to not download - just to return file path.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth: True. I believe you missed the leading sentence: _modify the function .. to .. not .. download anything .. but just return the path of the picture_. In essense, to leave out the download functions. We do not know anything about the pictures or there naming style, so _how_ to modify will have to be left for the questioneer to solve.